# openpyxl not recognizing cell.value and returning none

Tags: python, openpyxl

So i labled a dataset of about 500 xlsx-files and put the value (a string) to cell 'I3'
now I want to use openpyxl to read the value of that cell

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pathToData+file)
ws = wb.active
print(ws['I3'].value)
# returns None
```

I tried neighbour cells for example `print(ws['H3'].value)`, those return the correct value...
'I3' contains no formula or fancy formatting, just a plain text. Opened in Excel the Formatting says "General" for 'I3' as for 'H3'.

I assume something is wrong with the value of that cell, any ideas or experience on this one?

Comment: If you do `cell = ws['I3']` or `cell = ws.cell(row=3, column=9)`, can you then get `cell.value` or is it still `None`?
  And sort of dumb follow up question, but it has to be asked - did you save the Excel file after putting data in 'I3'?

Comment: Almost impossible to say anything without seeing a file. Openpyxl can only return whats in the file.

Answer (score 0):

By now I managed to "resolve" the issue.

I moved the file to a another computer and it worked. So I moved the file to C:\ on the first one and it also worked. Since it was previous stored in "Documents", which is synced by onedrive, I assume that onedrive somehow caused the problem.